# Android camera previews black image after taking photo

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera-intent

I have a small application which opens up the camera preview, you click a button to take a photo, and it displays on the screen after. I'm using an emulator to preview this, with a Nexus 5 API 25.

When I start the app, I can see the camera preview as it should be. However when I click to take a photograph, it gives a black screen where the image should be, and the `imageView.setBitmap(photo)` also displays this black image.

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1Wc0vmD284 and no one else seems to have this issue.

What could be the issue? Is it something to do with the sizing of the image after it's been taken? I've added file read and write permissions to my manifest file, and the photo preview does work without taking a picture so I'm assuming I have permission to use the camera.

Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //disable button if user has no camera
    if(!hasCamera() ) {
        myButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}



//Check if the user has a camrea
private boolean hasCamera() {
    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}


//Launching the camera
public void launchCamera(View view ){
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
       Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
       imageView.setImageBitmap(photo)
}
```

Comment: have you tried this on real device?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan it does in fact work on the real device. Still puzzled why it doesn't work on the emulator though. It's using my webcam

Comment: Same thing happened to me, but it happens sometimes otherwise it works fine. Maybe a bug

Answer (score 0):

```
private Uri fileUri;
public static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
 private void launchCamera() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImage");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

    fileUri=uriSavedImage;

}

private boolean hasCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

    @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image viewproduct_image
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                storeImage(photo);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
}
}
    private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {

    if (fileUri == null) {
        Log.d("TAG",
                "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileUri.getPath());
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Bitmap bitmap1= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
}
  public static boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(Activity activity, String permission) {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public static void requestForSpecificPermission(Activity activity, String granted_permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{granted_permission}, 101);
    }
}
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
if( checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ){

    }else {
        requestForSpecificPermission(
                activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

    if( checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ){


    }else {
        requestForSpecificPermission(
                activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){

    }else {
        requestForSpecificPermission(
                activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
}
```

try the above code it works fine till android 8